# Cookie is set but not visible in browser

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, cookies, jwt

Trying to build a blogging platform as a hobby project (expressjs + mysql + reactjs).
After deployment, cookie is being set but not visible under Storage/cookies, this issue does not exist in localhost.
Under networks tab, I can find set-cookie header in both request and response  headers.

I have tried and tested on chrome and firefox.

Request header:
[image: Request headers]
Response headers:
[image: Reqponse headers]

I have already gone through with all the possible solutions.

Login logic

```
const { password: hashedPassword, ...otherUserData } = data[0];

const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].id }, process.env.JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: "180d" });

res.cookie("access_token", token, {
    maxAge: 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
}).status(200).json(otherUserData);
```

On the frontend, `withCredentials = true` as default config. Im using axios for api calls.

Live link: https://code-daily.vercel.app/

Github link, if you want dive into the code: https://github.com/sachanayush47/CodeDaily

Answer (score 0):

The POST login route hits the `codedaily-production.up.railway.app` domain, receives a `set-cookie` header and sets the cookie for that domain. Every subsequent request to `codedaily-production.up.railway.app` has the `access_token` cookie in the request. Requests to `code-daily.vercel.app` is not going to have the cookie because it's not the host that set the cookie.

So when I checked the storage under the `codedaily-production.up.railway.app`, cookies are there.

You cannot fix this because the browser does not allow setting cross-domain cookies.

But if you really need the cookie for your frontend and backend, the standard way is to use an actual custom domain. We'll use `code-daily.com` as an example. The Vercel app could get served through `www.code-daily.com` and then the Railway backend is served through `api.code-daily.com`. Then setting the cookie domain as ".code-daily.com" will let both subdomains receive and send the cookie.

Comment: Probably this is the part that I'm missing. My frontend is on domain.com but my API is an AWS Lambda function. Somehow I need to add my lambda function to api.domain.com I guess. I'll confirm tomorrow.

Comment: It worked for me but how did you manage to work with the cookies on localhost and the different domain for the production environment?

Comment: I enabled "allow third party cookies" in the browser settings, it is just a workaround.